# LG Ultrafine 5K not working as standalone display on Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot Nvidia RTX 3090 GC Titan Ridge rev 2

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, display

Here are my system specs:

1. Dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04
2. AMD Ryzen 3700X, x570 Aorus, Nvidia RTX 3090 GPU
3. Gigabyte Titan Ridge 2
4. LG 5K Ultrafine monitor (intended to be used as a standalone monitor)
5. Old Asus monitor with HDMI capability

My problem is that I get a display on my ultrafine 5K only when I plug in the second HDMI monitor. The 5K stopped getting display after I updated the Nvidia drivers. It works fine at 4K when I connect it to a second display but not on its own. The monitor works fine as a standalone monitor on Windows.

Can someone help me fix this? Please share your experience if you faced the same problem and could get it running

Answer (score 2):

So, I may have found an answer to my problem.

I followed the recommendations of this blog [post](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-nvidia-drivers-410-break-ubuntu-18-04-with-gtx-1050/) and combined with blocklisting nouveau from this [post](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and it all seems to work fine.

One more thing which I had to do was connect 2 DP ports from the GPU to the Titan Ridge instead of just one. I had not done this earlier and could still get things running on Windows 10 at 4K (which I was okay with) which is why I did consider that Ubuntu might need an extra display port input.

In the hindsight the solution was easy, but I just couldn't wrap my head around it. Now I am getting a 5K display on Ubuntu 20.04. I have not checked if I get 5K on Windows or not but feel free to add comments related to that or check out other posts. My main issue feels resolved: getting my display to run on Ubuntu after installing the Nvidia Drivers 460 for RTX 3090.

[This](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/109312/16) post was also very useful for me to get a general idea as to what I should be looking into. I also installed nvidia-driver-455 from the download file with the libglvnd support with no luck, and then installed the latest driver without removing the original 455 version. I don't know if I needed to do that but everything seems to be working for now so I won't meddle with it.